# How to translate all messages in the Auth0 Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, auth0

I found how to translate most of the Lock 10 widget by setting the 'Extra settings' under 'Advanced' tab to e.g. the following:

```
{"language":"nl"}
```

That works fine for most of the Lock widget, but not for everything, e.g.

- "Login with WordPress username"
- "There was a problem with your log in"

and probably some more.

Is there some other setting I would need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text *"Login with WordPress username"* belongs to the Auth0 Wordpress plugin itself and not the Auth0 Lock widget so that's why you won't see any changes despite changing the Lock language setting; the plugin does not currently support I18N.

If you really need to display that option you can submit an improvement request to support I18N on the plugin itself; you can use the GitHub repository (https://github.com/auth0/wp-auth0) to submit the issue. Additionally, if you don't really require that option to be enabled you can hide the text by disabling the option *WordPress login enabled* in the plugin settings.

Regarding the other piece of text you mentioned I wasn't able to track the source of it, but if it comes from Lock you should also try to use the `languageDictionary`; see the following links for additional information on this:

- [Lock Customization - `languageDisctionary`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#languagedictionary-object-)
- [Lock Customization - Error Messages](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customizing-error-messages)

Answer (score 0):

plugins usually come with .po files that contain the plugin strings in the default language, one way to translate the default messages a plugin will show is using [Locotranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

install locotranslate plugin 
then go to locotranslate > plugins> choose your plugin> choose a language you want to translate to